# Problems with undefined props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, error-handling, components

i propgramed a todo-app in React. i create components for several parts. Now everytime i try to run the app it will be not displayed.

i alwas get that error Uncaught TypeError: todo is undefined in footer.js:15.

I create a todo-list app and put all my todos in an array where i have the use-state todo. This is the property i pass todo = {todo} ind my component Todocounter which is in the file footer.

I tried to rename the prop and to change its postion in the footer in order to invoke in the right place.

This is the app.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import InputTodos from './input.js';
import ListTodos from './list.js';
import TodoCounter from './footer.js';
import ClearButton from './clearbutton.js';

function App() {
  // create usestates for todos
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);

  // render all components i have in diffrent files
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="header">
          <InputTodos todo={todo} setTodo={setTodo} />
        </div>
        <div className="containerMid">
          <ListTodos todo={todo} />
        </div>
        <div className="footer">
          <TodoCounter todo={todo} />
        </div>
        <div className="buttonCleardiv">
          <ClearButton todo={todo} setTodo={setTodo} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is the footer.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import './App.css';

// use effect to show whenever the array will change from completed todos to not completed
function TodoCounter(props) {
  const { todo } = props;
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(0);
  const [notCompleted, setNotCompleted] = useState(0);

  // filter between completed todos and not completed todos with cheackking the bolean status
  function counttodos(props) {
    const { todo } = props;
    return {
      completed: todo.filter((todo) => todo.isChecked).length,
      notCompleted: todo.filter((todo) => !todo.isChecked).length,
    };
  }
  //with the useeffect hook set the todos on completed or not completed if sth changes on the todos
  useEffect(() => {
    const { completed, notcompleted } = counttodos(todo);
    setCompleted(completed);
    setNotCompleted(notcompleted);
  }, [todo]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Completed: {completed}</p>
      <p>Not Completed: {notCompleted}</p>
      <p>Todos: {todo.length} </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoCounter;
```

Comment: Change `function counttodos(props) {` to `function counttodos(todo)`, and remove the line after it `const { todo } = props;`. Also move `counttodos` out of the component, or inline it's code inside `useEffect`.

Comment: how do you mean to move counttodos out of the component, ir inline it ? i dont know exatly how i should do it. So far thank you for your aswer

Comment: Storing computed values (`completed` and `notcompleted`) in state is unnecessary and will likely lead to problems. Just define them as variables without the whole state, function, and use effect setup.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `counttodos` function out of the component, so it won't be re-created on render. Because you pass `todos` as a parameter to the function, and it's not wrapped with another object, you can use it directly without destructuring it:

```
// filter between completed todos and not completed todos with cheackking the bolean status
function counttodos(todos) {
  return {
    completed: todos.filter(todo => todo.isChecked).length,
    notCompleted: todos.filter(todo => !todo.isChecked).length,
  };
}
```

In the component itself, call `counttodos`, and use the computed values directly without storing it a state (see this [comment by @HenryWoody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75439053/problems-with-undefined-props-in-react?noredirect=1#comment133108193_75439053)):

```
function TodoCounter({ todo }) {
  //with the useeffect hook set the todos on completed or not completed if sth changes on the todos
  const { completed, notcompleted } = counttodos(todo);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Completed: {completed}</p>
      <p>Not Completed: {notCompleted}</p>
      <p>Todos: {todo.length} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```